# _NT_SYMBOL_PATH format

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to use windbg more, and I keep having problems with the symbol cache. It isn't clear to me what the format of the string is supposed to be.

I have a few requirements:

- use Microsoft's server http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
- use symbols from our software that are archived at `\\\foo\Build1234`
- use a local cache at `c:\dev\symbols`

The archive of symbols from our distributed build at `\\\foo\Build1234` are not organized as a symbol server. If I understand it correctly, I need to use the cache keyword.

Given these requirements, does this look like a properly formatted srvpath:

```
cache*\\foo\Build1234;srv*c:\dev\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

**Edit:**

I just started reading Advanced Windows Debugging and I had misinterpreted how the cache keyword works. I thought it was a way of telling the debugger that the folder is just a folder of files and not a symbol server. After Michael left his comment, I reread the section and see that it indeed works as Michael described.

Now I'm confused by when you use a `;` or a `*` to separate paths/URLs. And when you need the `srv*` prefix. In the online help for windbg they give this example:

```
\\someshare\that\cachestar\ignores;srv*c:\mysymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;cache*c:\mysymbols;\\anothershare\that\gets\cached
```

The symbols from `\\\someshare` are not cached, symbols from Microsoft are cached in `c:\mysymbols`, and `c:\mysymbols` is used as the cache for any other paths to the right of the `cache*` directive.

The occasional use of `srv*` is confusing me -- I don't understand why the first and last paths aren't prefixed with `srv*`.

**Edit 2:**

This is slowly starting to make sense to me. The `srv` directive is used for symbol servers, and not for normal symbol directories. So, I believe the answer to my original question is this:

```
\\foo\Build1234;cache*c:\dev\symbols;srv*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Comment: Related: [How to set up symbols in WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
SRV*C:\dev\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;\\foo\build1234
```

Should work fine, if `\\foo\build1234` is just flat PDB's.  Cache isn't needed here; you just need to add the directory to your symbol path.

The cache keyword specifies where you want to cache your symbol files, and is useful for caching symbols locally from non-indexed shares (like `\\foo\build1234`)

```
cache*C:\dev\symbols;SRV*C:\dev\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;\\foo\build1234
```

The above path would store symbols from MS's symbol server and your symbol share to your local machine in C:\dev\symbols.

To debug symbol issues using windbg, do

```
!sym noisy
.reload <some exe or DLL in your session>
```

And then do some action that would force the PDB to be loaded.  You'll see where windbg is looking for files, and if it rejects a PDB why it did so.

```
!sym quiet
```

Will then suppress symbol prompts.

Comment: When having symbol problems, I always use ".reload -f -a" after turning on noisy loads.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Your answer is correct. What I actually ended up doing is slightly different though. I put the \\\foo\build1234 at the beginning of the path so it is never cached, specified my global cache that I want to use for everything, then added the Microsoft URL. This way, any additional paths I append during debugging will use my global cache, which is how I want this to behave. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a detailed post on debugging issues with symbols loading.

[Loading symbols in Windbg](http://www.technlg.net/windows/symbol-server-path-windbg-debugging/)