# Visual Studio loadyng symbols from unexistent symbol path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cryengine

I can't debug any C++ project because they freeze when I get this:

```
Loading symbols for xyz.exe from symbol path:
 E:/....
```

The thing is that I don't have any hard drive with the letter `E:`, I have tried everything and I do not know what to do!! How can I fix that ?

Comment: what is your symbol path? environment variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`.

Comment: Idk what I did, This morning I started the computer and the debugger is working when I attach it to the process 'foo.exe' but when I try to directly debug it It says that no .pdb could be found for foo.exe. How I check my 'NT_SYMBOL_PATH' ?

Comment: it's an environment variable... from the command prompt, `set _nt_symbol_path`. See also: [Setting Symbol and Executable Image Paths in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439330(v=vs.85).aspx) and [_NT_SYMBOL_PATH format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967043/nt-symbol-path-format).